# Missing piece between libjpeg-turbo & h264 ffmpeg C/C++

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, data-conversion, libjpeg-turbo

### On the left side I have a buffer with decoded pixels that I can get in two formats:

*RGB interleaved/packed* where bytes in buffer are `R0G0B0R1G1B1....`

or

*YUV444 interleaved/packed* where bytes in buffer are `Y0U0V0Y1U1V1...`

(`JCS_RGB` or `JCS_YCbCr` in jpeglib.h)

(Please note that I use libjpeg-turbo because I need to decompress a cropped region of the image. (`jpeg_crop_scanline()`))

### On the right side I have x264 codec via ffmpeg that support only planar pixel formats:

yuv420p, yuvj420p, yuv422p, yuvj422p, yuv444p, yuvj444p, nv12, nv16, nv21, yuv420p10le, yuv422p10le, yuv444p10le, nv20le

*yuv444p*  where bytes in buffer are `Y0Y1Y2...U0U1...V0V1...`

according to *ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264*

### I have some ideas already:

- Decompress Jpeg to *RBG888* in buffer 1 then libswscale to *yuv420p* in buffer 2 and encoding. (copy)
- Decompress Jpeg to *YUV444 interleaved* in buffer 1 then SSSE3 magic in buffer 1 to *yuv444p* and encoding. (no copy)
- or else.

### What would be the <del>most effective</del> fastest way ?

I which to avoid buffer copy.

Movie have the same width & height than Jpegs.

Comment: "Most effective way" is not well defined. There is an option to use `sws_scale` for converting ordered y,u,v,y,u,v to planar YUV. There is a "trick" using BGR24 to GBRP conversion, and reordering the planes by reordering the pointers. Assuming libjpeg needs to convert from YUV to RGB when `JCS_RGB` is selected, and FFmpeg needs to convert back to YUV, the suggested solution may be more effective. I don't know if BGR24 to GBRP implementation is well optimized, but it's a more interesting solution.

Comment: I don't know a bunch about image processing, but does the question amount to "how do I take an array of the form { y_0, u_0, v_0, y_1, u_1, v_1, ... } and convert it in-place into { y_0, y_1, ..., u_0, u_1, ..., v_0, v_1, ... }?"

Comment: @DanielMcLaury yes ! could be one of the solution I need.

Comment: There is an option to lossless crop a ROI out of JPEG image without decoding and re-encoding. [jpegtran](https://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran) supports the feature. The fastest way may be "cropping without re-encoding" and decoding the cropped JPEG using FFmpeg (without using libjpeg-turbo). The cropping must be in "blocks" of 16x16 pixels - you may refine the cropping when using FFmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with using the RGB version of the libx264 encoder, you can use the rgb24 and bgr24 pixel formats without conversion.

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264rgb
...
    Supported pixel formats: bgr0 bgr24 rgb24
```

Comment: Thank you. For the record I have to use avcodec_find_encoder_by_name( "libx264rgb" ); because both codecs share the same AV_CODEC_ID_H264.

Answer (score 1):

JPEG images are normally stored in YUV420 pixel format.
Selecting `JCS_RGB` means that libjpeg applies YUV to RGB color conversion.
Assuming the H.264 encoded stream has to be in YUV444 pixel format, we may want to save the time of converting YUV to RGB and back from RGB to YUV.

The answer is going to show how to convert data ordered y,u,v,y,u,v to planar YUV444p format using `sws_scale`.

The solution uses AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24 to AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP conversion.
Since GBRP (planar GBR) is rarely used, the implementation may not be well optimized.
I don't know if it's going to be faster or slower compared to other solutions...

---

- RGB24 pixel format in ordered r,g,b,r,g,b... and pretends to be y,u,v,y,u,v...
- GBRP pixel format is G plane, B plane, R plane and and pretends to be Y plane, U plane, V plane

The planes order is G,B,R instead of R,G,B.
We may adjust the planes order by setting the orders of the pointers to the planes.

---

Start by creating input sample in y,u,v,y,u,v... format (using FFmpeg CLI):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=1 -filter_complex "format=yuvj444p,extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v];[u][v][y]mergeplanes=0x001020:gbrp" -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 yuvyuv.yuv`

The file `yuvyuv.yuv` is used as input for testing the solution (testing without using libjpeg).

---

The following code sample, reads the input, uses `sws_scale` for converting data ordered y,u,v to planar YUV, and stores the output to binary file `yuv_planar.yuv`.

Code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}


void convertYUV444ToYUV444p(const unsigned char *yuv_in, int width, int height)
{
    struct SwsContext* sws_context = nullptr;
    const int in_linesize[1] = {3 * width}; // YUV ordered stride (as y,u,v,y,u,v...)
    const int out_linesize[3] = {width, width, width}; // YUV planar stride (Y plane, U plane, V plane).

    //Allocate frame for storing YUV planar.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    AVFrame* pYUVFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    pYUVFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ444P; //AV_PIX_FMT_YUV444P;  //Select YUVJ444 (instead of YUV444) because the data is in "JPEG YUV format".
    pYUVFrame->width = width;
    pYUVFrame->height = height;
    int sts = av_frame_get_buffer(pYUVFrame, 0);

    if (sts < 0)
    {
        return;  //Error!
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //Convert ordered YUV to planar YUV
    //Use RGB24 to GBRP conversion (GBRP is planar format: Green plane, Blue plane, Red plane).
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    sws_context = sws_getContext(width, height,
                                 AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height,
                                 AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    const uint8_t* in_planes[1] = {yuv_in};

    //Reorder the pointers, to match the GBR planes order (first G [U], then B [V] then R [Y])
    //Y is the applies R channel, U is the applies G and V is the applies B channel of GBRP
    uint8_t* out_planes[3] = {pYUVFrame->data[1], pYUVFrame->data[2], pYUVFrame->data[0]};

    int response = sws_scale(sws_context, in_planes, in_linesize,
                             0, height, out_planes, out_linesize);

    if (response < 0)
    {
        printf("Error: sws_scale response = %d\n", response);
        return;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //Write YUV planar output to binary file (for testing)
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    FILE* f = fopen("yuv_planar.yuv", "wb");
    fwrite(pYUVFrame->data[0], 1, width*height, f);
    fwrite(pYUVFrame->data[1], 1, width*height, f);
    fwrite(pYUVFrame->data[2], 1, width*height, f);
    fclose(f);

    //Convert to PNG image for testing (the PNG image is in RGB color space):
    //ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -video_size 192x108 -pixel_format yuvj444p -i yuv_planar.yuv rgb_image.png
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    sws_freeContext(sws_context);
    av_frame_free(&pYUVFrame);
}



int main()
{  
    //Build input pattern in y,u,v,y,u,v format (for testing):
    //ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=1 -filter_complex "format=yuvj444p,extractplanes=y+u+v[y][u][v];[u][v][y]mergeplanes=0x001020:gbrp" -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 yuvyuv.yuv

    const int width = 192;
    const int height = 108;
    uint8_t *yuv_in = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(width*height*3);

    //Read input image for binary file (for testing)
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    FILE* f = fopen("yuvyuv.yuv", "rb");
    fread(yuv_in, 1, width*height*3, f);
    fclose(f);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    convertYUV444ToYUV444p(yuv_in, width, height);

    av_free(yuv_in);

    return 0;
}
```

---

For testing, we may convert the output to PNG image (using FFmpeg CLI):

`ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -video_size 192x108 -pixel_format yuvj444p -i yuv_planar.yuv rgb_image.png`

---

Input `yuvyuv.yuv` as Grayscale PNG image:
[image]

Output `yuv_planar.yuv` as Grayscale PNG image:
[image]

`rgb_image.png` (`yuv_planar.yuv` converted to colored PNG image):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can directly decompress a jpeg image into a yuv420p planar buffer by using `v_samp_factor` and `jpeg_read_raw_data()`.
See [gst_jpeg_dec_decode_direct()](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/blob/1.20.4/subprojects/gst-plugins-good/ext/jpeg/gstjpegdec.c#L863) of GStreamer.